# PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE flag not present in UserAccountControl attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2003, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to check through LDAP if an ActiveDirectory user has the PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE flag set. I found the UserAccountControl attribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-useraccountcontrol): it works for all other flags but it doesn't work for this flag. I only need to read it, not to write.

I'm using Java with UnboundID LDAP SDK (https://ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java/).

Here is my JUnit test code.

```
public static enum UACFlags {
    SCRIPT(0x0001),
    ACCOUNTDISABLE(0x0002),
    HOMEDIR_REQUIRED(0x0008),
    LOCKOUT(0x0010),
    PASSWD_NOTREQD(0x0020),
    PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE(0x0040),
    ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED(0x0080),
    TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT(0x0100),
    NORMAL_ACCOUNT(0x0200),
    INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT(0x0800),
    WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT(0x1000),
    SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT(0x2000),
    DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD(0x10000),
    MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT(0x20000),
    SMARTCARD_REQUIRED(0x40000),
    TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION(0x80000),
    NOT_DELEGATED(0x100000),
    USE_DES_KEY_ONLY(0x200000),
    DONT_REQ_PREAUTH(0x400000),
    PASSWORD_EXPIRED(0x800000),
    TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION(0x1000000);

    private int flag;

    private UACFlags(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}

@Test
public void testLDAP() throws LDAPException {
    LDAPConnection connection = //GET CONNECTION

    String username = "....";
    String search = "(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")";

    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("DC=....,DC=....", SearchScope.SUB, search, SearchRequest.ALL_USER_ATTRIBUTES);
    SearchResult result = connection.search(request);
    SearchResultEntry entry = result.getSearchEntries().get(0);

    Attribute a = entry.getAttribute("userAccountControl");
    int val = a.getValueAsInteger();
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(val));

    EnumSet<UACFlags> flags = EnumSet.noneOf(UACFlags.class);
    for (UACFlags f : UACFlags.values()) {
        if ((val & f.flag) == f.flag) {
            flags.add(f);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("FLAGS: " + flags);
}
```

I set up the flag on AD Users and Computers and it works as expected. I only want to check the flag programmatically, using Java and LDAP. Other solutions than UserAccountControl attribute are ok!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

That is, unfortunately, expected.

Microsoft uses the [`ADS_USER_FLAG_ENUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Iads/ne-iads-ads_user_flag) enumeration in a couple places:

1. The `userAccountControl` attribute when using LDAP, and
2. The `userFlags` property when using the WinNT provider.

The `ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` flag can only be used [when using the WinNT provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/ADSI/reading-user-cannot-change-password-winnt-provider), which I'm not sure you can do from Java.

When you click that 'User cannot change password' checkbox in AD Users and Computers, it doesn't actually change the `userAccountControl` attribute. In reality, it adds two permissions on the account:

1. Deny Change Password to 'Everyone'
2. Deny Change Password to 'SELF'

There is a description of how to look for those permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/ADSI/reading-user-cannot-change-password-ldap-provider), but the examples are in C++ and VBScript. I don't know how to view the permissions in Java. [It seems difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784606/how-to-manage-ad-acls-using-java) and I can't find any real examples.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Appears from AD 2008 on that this is not a "real" value; but rather an [ACE within the ACL of the entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSI/user-cannot-change-password).

**THIS NO LONGER WORKS**
As far as I can tell.
Microsoft Active Directory has a neat Extensible matching value that should work called [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND)

So a simple LDAP Query Filter like:

```
(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=64)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to run the query with the indicated filter but the server responds with an empty set...

Comment: Are you sure there are accounts with the flag set? Try 
(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=64))